# Windows 8.1 not prompting for product key in OOBE

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, deployment, sysprep

Im testing my new deployment evrything works fine, but ( after sysprep) at the oobe it doesnt ask for a product key?
Even without an unattend file ?

Anybody an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you verify the installation doesn't already have a product key?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very much like the key is still present - even in OOBE.

Proceed through the setup and then check in computer properties for the key.  This will be located near the verification/activation buttons.

To see exactly what key windows thinks you have, you can also try a number of free key retrieval tools.

Comment: Thanks , i found tools to locate the key but not to delete it... I now added slmgr /upk , slmgr /cpky slmgr /rearm and then the slui 3 commands to my setupcomplete.cmd as workaround.

Comment: or are there also tools commands to delete it from wim or iso files ?